# NoMethodError in one of my models #show actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got the following code in my show.html.erb file:

```
<p>
 <b>Status:</b>

 <% if @server.serverUp?.to_s == "Up" %>
  <% @server.update_attribute(@server.serverStatus, 'Up') %>
      <span style="color: green;"> <%= @server.serverUp? %></span>
      <% else %>
        <span style="color: #ff0000;"> <%= @server.serverUp? %></span>
      <% end %>
</p>
```

My main concerns is with the line `<% @server.update_attribute(@server.serverStatus, 'Up') %>` which breaks my app from working. This line is supposed to save the status of the Server, whether it is "Up" or "Down", and save it in 'servers' table under the 'serverStatus' column.

However, when I go to http://localhost:3000/servers/id_of_server, where 'id_of_server' is a number from 1-300, the following error message appears:

```
NoMethodError in Servers#show

Showing C:/SIS/app/views/servers/show.html.erb where line #18 raised:

undefined method `=' for #<Server:0x60b9358>
Extracted source (around line #18):

15: <p>
16:   <b>Status:</b>
17:      <% if @server.serverUp?.to_s == "Up" %>
18:       <% @server.update_attribute(@server.serverStatus, 'Up') %>
19:           <span style="color: green;"> <%= @server.serverUp? %></span>
20:           <% else %>
21:             <span style="color: #ff0000;"> <%= @server.serverUp? %></span>
```

I don't seem to understand the error message, as I haven't used an equal sign in the extract of code provided. Any help would be appreciated.

If you guys need any more info let me know.

Thanks in advance

**Edit:** While I'm at it, I just wanted to ask whether I'm not following the RoR conventions by putting that type of code into the show.html.erb file as opposed to somewhere else? Because in the same file I also have another algorithm which reads all the attributes of a model, puts it into an array, and displays only the unique values.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write:

```
<% @server.update_attribute(:serverStatus, 'Up') %>
```

And yes: you should not update models in view. In your case it could cleanly live in a `before_save` or why not in an `after_initialize` callback in the model I guess.

Lastly: in Ruby, convention is snake case so `server_status` instead of `serverStatus`

Comment: nice, that solved the error, however the problem that exists now is that this value is not actually stored into the database. I need it to be saved in the database, and appear on the index.html.erb of my app. Any idea why it isn't saving?

Comment: Why do you say it's not saved? Did you check in console or elsewhere? Sometimes, you need to reload the object.

Comment: I checked the database, the index page and also in IRB. It didn't save it at all

Comment: in irb?... well move this logic from the view to see if it changes something.

Comment: IRB i.e. the console. Move the logic to where?
Edit: Ok, i moved it to the model class, but still no change O_o

Comment: Is there any validation in `Server` model..try using `<% @server.update_attribute!(:serverStatus, 'Up') %>`..it will raise an error if any validation is not met.

Comment: where you feel most comfortable. As I said before, the best is a callback in model

Comment: @rubyprince tried that out, but i doubt 'update_attribute!' is a valid method as I only get a NoMethodError error message

Comment: Assigning one value to your variable according to another is just non sense. Why don't you make it in a `before_save` callback? This way, it's done once for all

Comment: @teenomar..I was wrong..`update_attribute` uses `save(false)`..so it bypasses validation already..I was thinking about `update_attributes`..

Comment: Ok, finally got it to work by restarting the whole WEBrick server. What does the `before_save` method do, and how would i implement it?
What are the benefits of using it over the current method?

Comment: Not sure how your model is done. You should ask another question with details.

Comment: It enables to change serverstatus depending on serverup so that your data are coherent.